# JavaScript function formats

Tags: javascript, function

I've seen JavaScript files formatted two different ways and I have no idea what the differences are.

```
<script>

function foo () { /* a function */ }

</script>

name = { 

foo: function () { /* a function */ }
foo2: function () { /* a different function */ }
}
```

What is the difference between these two ways of writing JavaScript, and why would I do one verese the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second method creates the functions as members of the object `name`.  This has the effect of encapsulating them inside `name`, rather than creating them inside the global namespace.  JavaScript can be very problematic in terms of variable and function naming, due to the way it utilizes the global namespace.  For example, forgetting to use the `var` keyword when declaring a variable inside a function will cause the variable to have global scope instead of function scope.

So, that second method allows you to create just one variable at the global level, and use it as a container for several more variables and functions without worry of colliding with other global function & variable names.

A common pattern you'll see (and recommended in Douglas Crockford's *Javascript: The Good Parts*):

```
var myApplication = {
  var1: 'some variable';
  var2: 'some other variable';
  var3: 12345

  foo1: function() {
    // do something
  },
  foo2: function() {
    // do something else
  }
};
```

In effect, the only global variable I have created here is `myApplication`, and that is unlikely to cause a name collision with anything else in the global namespace.  I can call my functions like:

```
myApplication.foo1();
myApplication.foo2();
```

Comment: Interesting. Are var1, var2, and var3 variables that are "global" only to the encapsulated function? What if you wanted multiple instances of "myApplication" like it was a class. So you ended up with something like:
    myApplication1.foo(); myApplication2.foo();

Comment: @SharpBob to create multiple class instances, there's another method of creating the object using a constructor function. Different syntax.  Search around for javascript class constructors for examples

Answer (score 0):

The second form is called a namespace.

It let you define function and varibales inside it.

Think of it as a Class in java,

You can declare methods and attributes that are only accessible thru your namespace.

In your example, it let you define 2 function called foo.

One being global (the first one)
One being inside an object called name (the second one)

if you want to call the second one somewhere, you must provide the namespace
ex:

```
name.foo()
```